# Shiro - redirect to login page after session timeout

Tags: java, session, web.xml, shiro

I need to redirect my webapp (Java + angular) to login page when session is timed out.
Does shiro do the redirection automatically or shall this be handled by code?

I tried several hacks but didn't work for me.
I tried adding session timeout to my web.xml but it simply didn't take affect.
I tried updating my shiro.ini, but then couldn't login to my app anymore!

Can you please help to find what's wrong in these files or advice what sould be done in such a case.

Thanks in advance.

web.xml:

```html
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ResourceManager</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <!-- session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

  <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/Login.html</location>
  </error-page-->
  
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
     com.<our customized package>.logging.AppLifeCircleListener
     </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>shiro-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiro-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/Login.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
   </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/management/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/privilege/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/file-explorer/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

shiro.ini :

```css
[main]

# LDAP Settinng
contextFactory = com.ibm.datafabrication.web.server.security.JndiLdapContextFactoryExt
contextFactory.url = ldap://<host>:389
contextFactory.systemUsername = <...>
contextFactory.keyPath = <>
contextFactory.encodedSystemPassword = ...

ldapRealm = com.<>.ActiveDirectoryRealm
ldapRealm.ldapContextFactory = $contextFactory
ldapRealm.userSearchFilter = (sAMAccountName={0})
ldapRealm.groupNameAttribute = cn
ldapRealm.searchBase = DC=<...>,DC=<...>,DC=com
ldapRealm.groupRolesMap = dfp_users:user,dfp_admins:admin

# SQLite Setting
ds = org.sqlite.SQLiteDataSource
ds.url = jdbc:sqlite:<>.db
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = false
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Name=?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = WITH uname(name) AS (VALUES(?)) SELECT 'user' FROM Users, uname WHERE Users.Name=uname.name UNION ALL SELECT 'admin' FROM (SELECT Id FROM Users, uname WHERE Users.Name=uname.name) LEFT JOIN Admins on Id = Admins.UserId WHERE UserId NOT NULL
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = true
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher

authc.loginUrl = /Login.html
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

authcStrategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.FirstSuccessfulStrategy
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $authcStrategy

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> What I tired

# session timeout
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionMode=native
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 60000
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager

sessionValidationScheduler = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.ExecutorServiceSessionValidationScheduler
sessionValidationScheduler.interval = 30000
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionValidationScheduler = $sessionValidationScheduler

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

[urls]
/logout = logout
/css/** = anon
/images/** = anon
/plugins/** = anon
/favicon.ico = anon
/tdf.ico = anon
/Login.html = authc
...
/** = authc, roles[user]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave your `web.xml` as it is since Shiro has nothing to do with the configruation in this file. There is a difference in the `HttpSession` used by the `HttpServletRequest` of your servlet and the Shiro `Session`. They are completely different things. So don't get confused by the session configuration by the servlet and the one by  Shiro. We let Shiro handle your session in this case.

**Problems with your shiro.ini**
You are overriding the settings you are writing to the `DefaultWebSessionManager`:

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager // Define a sessionManager variable
securityManager.sessionMode=native
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 60000 // set a securityManager.sessionManager property
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager // override the property by setting the object
```

You have to set the object first:

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
securityManager.sessionMode=native
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 60000
```

You don't need the `ExecutorServiceSessionValidationScheduler` since a valdiator is provided by the `DefaultWebSessionManager` already. A working example could look like the following:

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
# Session timeout token_ttl_ms = 14 days
sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 1209600000
# Session valdiation = 15 minutes
sessionManager.sessionValidationInterval = 900000

securityManager = org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
```

**DefaultWebSessionManager**

The [DefaultWebSessionManager](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/session/mgt/DefaultWebSessionManager.html) provides all the functionality you are looking for out of the box (basically). When a session expires the `DefaultWebSessionManager` calls `onExpiration` on its [super](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/session/mgt/AbstractValidatingSessionManager.html) which notifys all its listeners about the expiration in the [SessionManager](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/session/mgt/AbstractNativeSessionManager.html). You simply could register a [SessionListener](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/session/SessionListener.html) to your `SessionManager` and trigger a reload or redirect at its `onExpiration` method. Maybe this approach is rather suitable for jsp/jspx applications.
Anyway, read how to register a session listener [here](https://shiro.apache.org/session-management.html#SessionManagement-SessionListeners) in the official docs.

**Alternative approach**

A different approach could be to have your client manage the session state and let it continuously check for expiration by calling your service. This could be done by a timer or in a loop in JavaScript.

**Note**

`org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher` is deprecated since 2010.
Use the [HashedCredentialsMatcher](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/credential/HashedCredentialsMatcher.html) directly and set its hashAlgorithmName property.

Comment: Thanks. It's obviouse to me that the web.xml and shiro are 2 different things... I'm just saying that I tried both.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I implemented a time out solution on my client side using @ng-idle/core angular package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-idle/core

https://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng2-idle/

I used the @ng-idle/keepalive as well to ping the server continuously and keep it alive:

```
handleIdle(){
  // sets an idle timeout of x seconds, for testing purposes.
 this.idle.setIdle(/*Config.SESSION_IDLE*/ this.sessionIdle);
 // sets a timeout period of y seconds. after x+y seconds of inactivity, the user will be considered timed out.
 this.idle.setTimeout(/*Config.SESSION_TIMEOUT*/ this.sessionTimeout);
 // sets the default interrupts, in this case, things like clicks, scrolls, touches to the document
 this.idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);

 this.idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => this.idleState = 'No longer idle.');
 this.idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
   this.idleState = 'Timed out!';
   this.timedOut = true;
 });
 this.idle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => {
         this.idleState = 'You\'ve gone idle!'
         this.idleModal.open();
     }    
 );
 this.idle.onTimeoutWarning.subscribe((countdown) => {
     this.idleState = 'You\'ve gone idle! Your session will be timed out in ' + countdown + ' seconds!';

     if (countdown == 1){
         window.location.href = "../logout";
     }
 });

 // sets the ping interval to z seconds
 this.keepalive.interval(/*Config.KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL*/this.keepAliveInterval);

 this.keepalive.onPing.subscribe(() => {
     this.lastPing = new Date();
     this.resourcesService.ping();
 });

 this.reset(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the **globalSessionTimeout**

The path is **WEB-INF/classes/shiro.ini**

```
sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 18000000
```

It will make the session last longer.