# How to trigger a redirect on session expiration in a Shiro SessionListener?

Tags: java, session-timeout, shiro

I've successfully registered a SessionListener in my Shiro configuration and the `onExpiration` method is being called. Now I want to redirect the user/browser to a "session expired" page. In the answer of UnlikePluto to question [Shiro - redirect to login page after session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50337049/shiro-redirect-to-login-page-after-session-timeout) it says

> You simply could register a SessionListener to your SessionManager and trigger a reload or redirect at its onExpiration method.

But how to trigger a redirect in that method? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Found a solution?

Comment: @0x45 No, unfortunately not.